# changing real time process priority in Linux ..?

Tags: process, linux-kernel, scheduling

My query is regarding engineering the priority value of a process. In my system, process A is running in RR at priority 83. Now I have another process B in RR, I want B's priority to be higher than A (i.e. I want B to be scheduled always compared to A).

To do this, what value should I choose for B. I have read in code that there is a penalty/bonus of 5 depending upon process's history.

Also, If I choose value 84 Or 85, is there any chance in some situations that my process is ignored.

Please help in engineering this value.

Comment: Are the processes similar in any way?  Do they do roughly the same type and quantity of i/o, use of memory, etc.?

Comment: qauntity of I/O, use of memory is alsmost same. Only difference is in the task done by them. Process B is for monitoring other processes whether they are live Or not. Process A does just normal activity. So that's why I want process B to be schedulled in priority than A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I got it. Real time tasks(FF/RR) are not governed by penalty/bonus rules. With O(1) scheduler, task with higher priority will be chosen. In my case process B will be scheduled if its priority is greater than process A.

Penalty/bonus is for SCHED_OTHER/SCHED_NORMAL.

Comment: Please add details of Kernel version and scheduler as different scheduler will have different logic.